# Windows 8(.1) Sleep 1 more ms than needed

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

`Sleep` on `Windows 8.1` x64 always lasts 1 more milliseconds than needed. For instance `Sleep(1)` lasts approximately 2 milliseconds, `Sleep(2)` - 3 etc. `timeBeginPeriod` is set to 1. On `Windows 7` works fine as expected (without excess millisecond). Is this behaviour is normal / possible to fix?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

long long int GetCurrent()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER counter;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter);

    return (1000000 * counter.QuadPart / Frequency.QuadPart);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    timeBeginPeriod(1);

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);

    const unsigned int count = 1000;

    long long int buffer[count];

    long long int lastTime = GetCurrent(), currentTime;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        currentTime = GetCurrent();

        buffer[i] = currentTime - lastTime;

        lastTime = currentTime;

        Sleep(1);
    }

    timeEndPeriod(1);

    FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", "w");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fprintf(file, "%ld\n", buffer[i]);

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `Sleep` guarantees you that it will sleep for *at least* the time you asked, probably more, at the scheduler's whim; it's always been like that, and you cannot rely on it to be precise especially in the lower end of its spectrum.

Comment: I understand this, but on `Windows 7` (and probably on other previous sytems) `Sleep` with `timeBeginPeriod` set in average was approximately requested value. But on `Windows 8.1` it always adds +1 excess ms. I thought this behaviour is quite strange.

Comment: Timers were tinkered with in Windows 8.1.  I get a mixed bag of 1 and 2 msec intervals with this code, it would work better if you could call Sleep() with infinite speed.  That's not in the cards.  Losing 1 msec sometimes is [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Use an actual timer instead of relying on Sleep() so Windows can do it properly.  timeSetEvent() is legacy, CreateTimerQueueTimer() is modern.

Comment: Try `NtDelayExecution`?

Comment: Have a look at QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency.  They may give you the resolution you are looking for.  You need to account for the time taken to execute the code if you want very high resolution sleeps.

Comment: `NtDelayExecution` with -10000 (1 ms) still lasts approx. 2 ms (-20000 = 3 ms etc). Although if less than 1 ms is passed (-1000 or 0.1 ms) it lasts approx. 1ms. Seems like excess 1 ms addition still exist, but passing less than 1 ms workaround it to total 1 ms. Something like that works `delay.QuadPart = -1; for (unsigned int i = 0; i < milliseconds; i++) NtDelayExecution(false, &delay);`

Comment: The name `Yield` was already taken (Windows 3.1 function) but that's a more appropriate name. `Sleep(1)` yields the CPU for one millisecond, but does not claim it back immediately.

Comment: When I needed precision timing in past applications, I've used a combination of Sleep (for delays > 1ms) and then the PerformanceCounter to precisely time the last ms. E.g. for 16.66667ms, I would sleep for 15ms with Sleep() and then poll the PerformanceCounter for the last 1.66667ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NtDelayExecution` workaround thanks to *Mehrdad*.

```
static NTSTATUS (__stdcall *NtDelayExecution)(BOOL Alertable, PLARGE_INTEGER DelayInterval) = (NTSTATUS (__stdcall*)(BOOL, PLARGE_INTEGER)) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtDelayExecution");

LARGE_INTEGER delay;

unsigned int milliseconds = 1;

delay.QuadPart = (milliseconds > 1) ? -10000LL * (milliseconds - 1) : -1LL;

NtDelayExecution(false, &delay);
```